# Label Expression If Statement remove Zeros

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, vbscript, arcgis-10.4

I am trying to perform a semi-complicated labeling expression that shows one field divided by another field and some additional fields with no division. The issue I ran into was that the denominator sometimes shows up as a 0. So, I need to build an if statement to perform the division if [TOT_HH_1] <> 0, do __ and if [TOT_HH_1] = 0, do __.

Also, there are three denominators that may or may not be 0. TOT_HH_1, 5 and 10.

Here is what I have so far.

```
Function FindLabel ([ELEM_1], [TOT_HH_1], [ELEM_5], [TOT_HH_5], [ELEM_10], [TOT_HH_10] )
  if ( [TOT_HH_1] <> 0 OR [TOT_HH_5] <> 0 OR [TOT_HH_10] <> 0) then
    FindLabel = Round ([ELEM_1] / [TOT_HH_1] , 2)  & " , " & Round ( [ELEM_5]/ [TOT_HH_5] , 2) & " , " & Round ( [ELEM_10] / [TOT_HH_10] , 2)  & "/" & [TOT_HH_1]  & " , " & [TOT_HH_5]  & " , " & [TOT_HH_10] 
  elif ( [TOT_HH_1] = 0 ) then
    FindLabel = 0  & " , " & Round ( [ELEM_5]/ [TOT_HH_5] , 2) & " , " & Round ( [ELEM_10] / [TOT_HH_10] , 2)  & "/" & [TOT_HH_1]  & " , " & [TOT_HH_5]  & " , " & [TOT_HH_10]
End Function
```

Edit:
Correct, the code in the answer worked great, here is a picture of what the labeling looks like.
[image]

Comment: If you want a good answer you should ask a question or explain what is happening with the code you have worked up.

Comment: So, what's the problem? elif is misspelled - should be else if. end if is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure what your calculation is trying to do, or what possible values are in your fields, but a few things to consider are:

1. VBScript doesn't have `elif` but rather `elseif`
2. You need to end `if` with an `end if`
3. You probably want to separate your `<> 0` out into separate `if` statements for when some have `0` and others don't (e.g. `TOT_HH_1 = 0` but `TOT_HH_5 <> 0`)

I've separated everything out into different if statements and set a variable for each calc.  The label then returns either a 0 or the value from each calc into your full label text.

```vbs
Function FindLabel ([ELEM_1], [TOT_HH_1], [ELEM_5], [TOT_HH_5], [ELEM_10], [TOT_HH_10] )
  dim val1
  dim val5
  dim val10
  val1 = val5 = val10 = 0

  if [TOT_HH_1] <> 0 then
    val1 = Round([ELEM_1] / [TOT_HH_1] , 2)
  end if

  if [TOT_HH_5] <> 0 then
    val5 = Round([ELEM_5] / [TOT_HH_5] , 2)
  end if

  if [TOT_HH_10] <> 0 then
    val10 = Round([ELEM_10] / [TOT_HH_10] , 2)
  end if

  FindLabel = val1 & ", " & val5 & ", " & val10 & " / " & [TOT_HH_1] & ", " & [TOT_HH_5] & ", " & [TOT_HH_10]
End Function
```